Partition error on Samsung Galaxy M02 phone
I have a Samsung Galaxy M02 phone. It showed me the error suddenly, and then I flashed successfully with Odin, then the phone worked fine for a few hours and switched off, failed to boot, and showed that same exact error message.


<!>
Partitions
Reason [check_secure_boot] vbmeta partition read failed
avb_util.c:199: ERROR: Failed to allocate memory.
[check_secure_boot] Buffer alloc failed for verification

Can someone tell me what to do now?
